# Apply Generalized Stokes to $R^2$ Line Integrals

Tags: surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Is there a simple way to apply generalize stokes theorem to $\int_{\partial C} f(x,y) ds$ for some $C\subset R^2$. I am stuck on what $\omega$ would be in the formula.

Comment: $\omega$ would be the $1$-form $f(x,y)ds$. You can write $ds$ in terms of $dx\wedge dy$ and then compute $\int_C d(f(x,y)ds)$.

Comment: How would you right in that terms. That’s what I’m stuck on @ElliotG